# Linux tools to find duplicate files?

Tags: linux, diff, files

I have a large and growing set of text files, which are all quite small (less than 100 bytes).  I want to diff each possible pair of files and note which are duplicates.  I could write a Python script to do this, but I'm wondering if there's an existing Linux command-line tool (or perhaps a simple combination of tools) that would do this?

**Update** (in response to [mfinni](https://serverfault.com/users/29373/mfinni) comment): The files are all in a single directory, so they all have different filenames.  (But they all have a filename extension in common, making it easy to select them all with a wildcard.)

Comment: I'm assuming that the filenames are not duplicates, only the contents?

Comment: http://www.pixelbeat.org/fslint/ if you are looking for contents above link may help you do that. :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There's the [fdupes](http://netdial.caribe.net/~adrian2/fdupes.html). But I usually use a combination of `find . -type f -exec md5sum '{}' \; | sort | uniq -d -w 36`

Comment: This variation worked for me: `find . -name "*.csv" | xargs md5sum | sort | uniq -D -w 34`  (I used uniq -D, and I prefer xargs to find -exec.)

Comment: +1 I was not aware of fdupes, that tool looks very useful.

Comment: @Daryl: Using `xargs` like this does not work for filenames with blanks, using `-exec` however does. Using `-type f` as additional argument to `find` (can be used together with `-name`) restricts the search to files.

Comment: +1 for fdupes, since it is fast for huge binary files, as well.

Comment: On some rare occasions I have had xargs not working (crashing after a certain amount of processed files) but not find -exec wich woked all the time. @fuenfundachtzig, one can use xargs -0 --delimiter="\n" to handle these kind of files.

Answer (score 6):

Well there is FSlint - which I haven't used for this particularly case, but I should be able to handle it: 
http://en.flossmanuals.net/FSlint/Introduction

Comment: +1 for FSlint. Very intuitive interface and powerful customization options.

Answer (score 3):

You almost certainly don't want to diff each pair of files.  You probably would want to use something like md5sums to get all the checksums of all the files and pipe that into some other tool that will only report back duplicate checksums.

Comment: You could reduce the number of md5sums calculated by only calculating md5sums for files that are of a size, for which there is more than one file of that size. So for all files that are of a unique size in bytes, you do not need an md5sum, since they cannot be duplicates of anything.

Answer (score 0):

I see fdupes and fslint mentioned as answers. jdupes is based on fdupes and significantly faster than either, fdupes ought to be considered deprecated at this point.